# Pin It button does not show count

Tags: pinterest

I have integrate "Pin It" button to share my product images on pinterest.com. But it does not show pin count in front of pin it button on my site. I have written following code.

This is my pin it button on my site

```
<a class="pin-it-button" target="_blank" count-layout="horizontal" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.techmodi.com/demo/bliise/products/MTY=/MTQ=/products&media=http://www.techmodi.com/demo/bliise/uploads/product/thumb/1341565713_89a084d6ff75306b0b7ed4c0a1d61916_medium.jpg&description=Nicholson Bag Black">
<img border="0" title="Pin It" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png">
</a>
```

& this js file is included before `<body>` tag closed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Please suggest me solution if anybody have.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the JavaScript file asynchronously. Replace your `script` tag with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d){
  var f = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0], p = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
  p.type = 'text/javascript';
  p.async = true;
  p.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
  f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);
}(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **always-show-count="true"** in anchor tag

Comment: Not only it doesn't work, but it also breaks W3C validation (if anybody even cares).